# Prove that a family of harmonic functions is a normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose $\Omega$ is an open, bounded, connected set. Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\overline\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of harmonic functions on $\Omega$ that belong to $C(\overline\Omega)$ such that $u \leq f$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$.

Can we show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a normal family?

Each $u$ should attain a minimum and maximum and it seems like one could apply the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem here, but how could we prove uniform boundedness and equicontinuity of the family?

Comment: For the uniform boundedness, you can use the maximum principle for the harmonic functions

Comment: What if $u_n = - n, n = 1,2,\dots ?$

Comment: I agree the maximum principle should be useful but how does that generalize to a family of harmonic functions? It only gives bounds on each individual harmonic function $u$ rather than the family $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @zhw. Not sure what you are implying if $u_n$ is as you defined.